# Android SQlite access not fast enough?

Tags: android, sqlite, udp

I have a strange issue with my application.

I have to send DB entries from a DB on phone 1 to DB on phone 2. The preocess is smart in the sense that it sends only the missing entries, so if in DB 1 I have 10 entries and in DB 2 I have 0, it sends 10 entries, but if only 5 of them are received by phone 2 (for any reason), the next time only the 5 missing entries are sent. Entries are sent one by one with UDP messages.
The fact is that I can never receive on the second phone all the entries at the first try, I have to try several times and every times I can receive only 3-4 of them. Messages are ok, I can see them on the sending side and on the receiveing side, so I guess it's a DB problem! Is it possible that the DB can't add rows fast enough respect to the arriving message rate?

Comment: Why are you using UDP? if you have used TCP (which guarantees delivery), you would not have this problem.

Comment: I highly doubt that SQLite is where the ball is getting dropped. I'd suggest you add some logging to the receiving end to determine exactly at what point a message gets dropped. See if the `INSERT` statement actually gets run for each message. Are you processing these in sequence as they arrive, or kicking off a new thread for each one?

Comment: I'm using UDP because I think TCP it not necessary AND because I had problem with the TCP server before :) The issue is not in the sending/receiving part because from my log I can see that all the messages are correctly sent and received.

Comment: I think you need to get a better handle on where the failure point really is. You can write a lot of data into SQLite, and it won't simply "ignore you" if it can't handle the speeds (you'll get timeout errors, etc.)

That being said, it may be worth creating a collection queue and a secondary processor that pulls from said queue to insert into the database.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you aren't waiting long enough between sends of your database entries. You can either extend that time or perform all of your inserts inside of a single transaction. When you don't use transactions, its entirely possible for inserts to take upwards of a second.

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     // Insert all the records here
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, I'll let you know, thanks. Looking better my log, I can see that UDP messages arrive quite at the same time (3 messages now, 3 messages 1 millisecond after)!